# Pods in a specific node don't have internet access

Tags: networking, docker, linux-networking, kubernetes, calico

Pods in a specific node (let's call it mynode) don't have access to the internet, remaining pods scheduled in other nodes do have internet access.

mynode has access to the internet, I can ssh into it, i can also launch standalone docker containers and they do have access to internet, but pods scheduled on the node don't.

Issue affects ingress and egress, kubelet is running on port 10250 and reachable via:
`curl https://localhost:10250 -k` returns `404 page not found`.

Context: My cluster has few nodes with same spec, yesterday I decided to upgrade OS(20.04 to 22.04) and so I removed the previous K8S cluster which was working fine, upgraded the OS on all nodes, reinstalled K8S, re-created the cluster, it all works smoothly on all nodes except for mynode, it is in ReadyState, seems fine, except it is not.

My CNI is calico. Calico pods(csi-node-driver and calico-node) on the node are in Running state, no restarts.

I followed the debugging page on k8s website, the HTTP server scheduled on the pod can not be reached, so this issue affects both **ingress and egress**.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue happened after the OS upgrade, so check CNI Plugin, CRI’s and Container Images of pods are up to date and compatible with the newer OS version 22.04.

The issue might happen because of various reasons like [network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#isolated-and-non-isolated-pods) blocking access, pod network configuration and Calico CNI issues. Follow below steps which may help to resolve your issue :

1. Go through coreDNS logs & pod logs to understand the issue, you will get more info by running the commands :

   **kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns**

   **kubectl logs podname**
2. Check any network policies blocking traffic to the pod.You will get more info by running the command : `kubectl get networkpolicy`
3. [Check required ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports) are open or not.
4. Check if the firewall rule within the pod may block the traffic.
5. Match pods CIDR and Calico's default is 192.168.0.0/16, refer [github comment](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2962#issuecomment-547979845) for more details.
6. If the HTTP server relies on DNS names, make sure [DNS resolution](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74955#issuecomment-470018455) is configured correctly within the cluster.

**Edit1**

7. Sometimes no issues with CoreDNS, but due to k8s network issues where traffic to ClusterIPs is not directed correctly to Pods. It may be because of Kube-proxy. Refer to k8s [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-service/) for troubleshooting guide.
8. Also check if Pod networks overlap with the host networks. Refer to [Installing a Pod network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) for more details.
9. Sometimes network related features are not loaded during upgrade and when you do get into such pods, you are working as a root user. So try to do `apt-get update` and then later you can do `apt-get install curl.`

Comment: network policy i don't have any, kube-dns logs does not show any errors related to the pod, i am trying, curl and nslookup and nothing, Ip of the pod is indeed in 192.168.0.0/16. the firewall i cleared iptables in the node, the pod is a basic ubuntu image with sleep infinity, it works on other nodes, just not on this one, the issue is internet overall, i can't curl not even to an ip

Comment: Check the **Edit1** in the answer for further, make sure container images used by the specific pods are compatible with OS 22.04 version. Check required ports open & also sometimes it might be an issue with port range.

Comment: The solution at the end was restarting the server, no clue why, apt update was not working, I had to spawn radial/busyboxplus:curl image to be able to use networking tools, not even the cluster's DNS was reachable. if i had to speculate i would say maybe some service was did not restart or something, no idea though

Comment: I am glad to hear this has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was to restart the server ...

Answer (score 2):

Kubelet showing you `404` is expected since that URL doesn't exists.
try the following:

```
curl -k https://localhost:10250/healthz
```

I would start with `ip_forward` check on the faulty node

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If that is not the case then I'll check the policies that are being enforced by Calico

```
kubectl get networkpolicy -A
kubectl get gnp
kubectl get cnp -A
```

Next I would verify `nat` is enabled for the IPPool

```
kubetl get ippool -o yaml
```

Check the gateway.

> Note: Flushing iptables might temporarily drop your connection, make sure you have a console connection handy.

Flushing IPtables might not be bad idea too, might be some sort of rule that overstayed its welcome.

```
iptables -F
```